# Sencha Touch Store Add replaces record 1

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I extended an Ext.data.Store (i.e users with model user) but when I iterate over custom JSON response and add each record, it replaces the first record and so the store consist of just one record instead of many

Here is my code (in image format) notice in line 215 i added a model on store on  each iteration:
[image]

And here is the console output w/c only shows 1 on getCount():
[image]

I tried many solutions, and that includes changing the 'id' attribute to something else and also differ my user model to users model

But I have another store that is adding fine without problems.

EDIT: I tried adding it through javascript console and still it replaces the record 1:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you get the users in a plain json list? Or are they wrapped in a SINGLE object like {users: [{},{},{}], totalCount: 3}

Comment: oh yeah, the list is parsed ok pls. see console log lines 214, i created a model on each list item and they equal to 3, and should be, and everytime I add each model, this replaces the first record

Answer (score 0):

The store's `add` function will automatically handle creation of the model(s).  Your callback should be as simple as this:

```
callback: function(optionsusers, successusers, responseusers) {
    loadingLoginModal.hide();

    var responseusersJSON = Ext.JSON.decode(responseusers.responseText);
    userStore.add(responseusersJSON);

    loadingLoginModal.destroy();
    that.showHomeView();
}
```